# SignalR is hitting database twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

The database table(DummyData) has a single column(Message) and only one record/row with value "hello".I'm using signalR to display this value on a webpage. Whenever this value is updated in DB, the text on the webpage is also updated without refresh. All this works fine.

The problem I see is, the app is hitting the database twice. Is this by design or a bad code. (The page is opened only once. No other instances)

**aspx**

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var notify = $.connection.notificationsHub;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                notify.server.notifyAllClients();
            });

            notify.client.displayNotification = function (msg) {               
                $("#newData").html(msg);                              
            };            
        });
    </script>
    <span id="newData"></span>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
public string SendNotifications()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Message] FROM [dbo].[DummyData]";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
                    command.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        message = reader[0].ToString();
                    }                    
            }
            return message;
        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                NotificationsHub obj = new NotificationsHub();
                obj.NotifyAllClients();                
            }            
        }
```

**NotificationsHub.cs**

```
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
 {
  Messages obj = new Messages();
  public void NotifyAllClients()
   {
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
    context.Clients.All.displayNotification(obj.SendNotifications());
   }

  public override Task OnConnected()
   {
    NotifyAllClients();
    return base.OnConnected();
   }
  public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
   {
    NotifyAllClients();
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
   }
 }
```

Here is how the breakpoints are hit on debug:

- on page load:

  1. OnConnected()
  2. NotifyAllClients()
  3. SendNotifications()
  4. NotifyAllClients()   `//why is this hit again`
  5. SendNotifications()
- when I run `update DummyData Set Message='helloworld'`

  1. dependency_OnChange()
  2. NotifyAllClients()
  3. SendNotifications()
  4. dependency_OnChange() `//hit a second time here too`
  5. NotifyAllClients()
  6. SendNotifications()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for the initial page load I'm assuming this:

You're calling `NotifyAllClients` upon a client connection in `OnConnected` and then in the client's `done` function there's another call to `NotifyAllClients`.

Comment: Could you please advice how to prevent the second hit

Comment: Leave out one call of the two, doesn't really matter which one imo.